# Finding analytic function with given condition

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have this task from complex analysis: Find analytic function $ f(z) $ such that $ |f(z)|=e^{{\rho}^2\cos(2\theta)} $ where $ z=\rho e^{i\theta}. $ I'm guessing I should use Cauchy-Riemann conditions, but I'm not sure how to do it. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\rho e^{i\theta})^2=\rho^2e^{2i\theta}$, you have $\operatorname{Re}\bigl((\rho e^{i\theta})^2\bigr)=\rho^2\cos(2\theta)$. Besides,$$e^{\operatorname{Re}\bigl((\rho e^{i\theta})^2\bigr)}=\left|e^{(\rho e^{i\theta})^2}\right|.$$So, take $f(z)=e^{z^2}.$

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you tell me how to show that this function is analytic? I assume I have to find imaginary part of this function and use Cauchy-Riemann in polar coordinates?

Comment: My function is $\exp\circ q$, where $q(z)=z^2$. And if you compose two analytic functions, you get an analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $|e^w|= e^{\text{Re}(w)}$.  Now $\rho^2 \cos(2\theta) = \text{Re}(\rho^2 e^{2i\theta}) = \text{Re}(z^2)$.